# Django: How to upload an image to MEDIA_ROOT upon Model Creation

Tags: django

I have the following model with an `ImageField()` that extends `User`:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   photo = models.ImageField()
   apartment = models.ForeignKey('Apartment')
```

However, when I create the model from a form, the image does not save to my MEDIA_ROOT directory. This seems like very basic functionality but I can't find a straightforward answer anywhere.

When I create a User in the admin section the file saves but not when I create it with my form. What do I do?

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet of what your form looks like? I suspect the issue will be there or in the view as @RemcoGerlich has pointed out too. Have a look at the example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: I was about to say that, and if not there then the problem might be the view.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich You were correct. I'll post my solution as the answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the view.

First I had:

```
...
photo = request.POST['photo'] # <--- 'POST', incorrect
tenant = Tenant(user=user, photo=photo, apartment=apartment)
tenant.save()
```

But corrected it to:

```
photo = request.FILES['photo'] # <--- 'FILES', correct
tenant = Tenant(user=user, photo=photo, apartment=apartment)
tenant.save()
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/

**Note:**

I also had to change my form tag in my template from

```
<form action="/account/create_account/" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="/account/create_account/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```